# Simple Admob Questions

Tags: android, admob

I have been a long time stalker to this awesome site and It has helped me many times. I am releasing this OpenGL ES based 2d game for android soon and I got questions related to admob:

1. I am using the same ad unit for all the various screens (main menu, in-game, help screen) of the game.. Is it ok to do this?
2. The in-game ad unit displays ad only when user pauses the screen... It will be always running in the background and is visible and clickable only when user pauses the screen... will google consider this a scammy way of getting impressions?
3. Does admob pay per impressions too?
4. What is the initial amount I should pay for Google PlayStore? (I tried searching in google I promise)

Also please mention precautionary measures to take with admob if you happen to think of one...

Comment: Could you clarify what you are asking about pay for google playstore, I am assuming you are wondering the cost of posting an app on the google play store?

Comment: That is right.. the cost of posting an app on playstore is what I asked... And also plz clarify the other qstns.. :)

Comment: the fee to deploay apps in play store is 25$

Comment: For 2, it's bad practice to let ads refresh in the background and not showing them. A better implementation would be to just request the ad when the user hits the pause button.  If you're super concerned about latency, you could consider turning off your refresh rate, requesting 1 ad in the background, show it when the user clicks pause, and then make a new ad request yourself in code when the user leaves the pause menu.  Letting ads refresh gives you inflated impressions, which you don't get paid for, reduces your click through rate, and uses unnecessary network connectivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a former user of admob:

1. Yes.
2. Nope. You can even show the ad while the game runs. But you can always read their integrity policy. They change it once in a while.
3. As far as I know only video ads pay for impressions. I'm not sure if admob allows supports video ads. Image and Javascript banners do not pay for impressions.
4. Here is the answer: http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113468

As of precautionary measures, as I said, read their developer integrity policy. No matter what anybody tells you in this forum about that topic, google could update their policy the next day, rendering any advice given obsolete. Plus the integrity policy is about a page long.