# android-shall i wait for new admob or carry on with legacy admob ?new admob is not available in india yet

Tags: android, admob

I have created my first andriod app.I want to publish it in the market.I found out that google released new admob and this update not available in india.So shall i wait for the new one or carry on with old admob sdk??Please help me out.
[Simple Admob Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12527464/simple-admob-questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new web interface for Admob does not yet appear to have been rolled out in India. But there is no new SDK. The only change is that with the new UI you will get new AdUnit Ids.

But the migration process from the current UI to the new UI is good, and any existing AdUnits will continue to work.

So I would suggest not to wait. Publish your app with your current AdUnits. You can always republish later.